# What are the proper steps to debug that why mongoDB server is not running?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have install the mongodb version 4.4.5

But now when i start the mongo in my terminal it shows me an error.

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Mon 2021-04-12 13:02:55 PKT; 2min 14s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 1159 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 1159 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)

اپریل 12 13:02:54 hassan-Latitude-E5570 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
اپریل 12 13:02:55 hassan-Latitude-E5570 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
اپریل 12 13:02:55 hassan-Latitude-E5570 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

Comment: I don't really see how upgrading PHP would cause issues for the mongo server itself? Exactly what did you do when you upgraded PHP? And from what version to what version? What OS?

Comment: from 7.2 to 7.3 and i am actually confused does updating php version create impact or something else that's why i am asking about steps.

Comment: Upgrading PHP shouldn't impact the Mongo server itself and shouldn't hinder that server from starting. That's why I asked _"Exactly what did you do when you upgraded PHP"_. Please edit your question to include a proper description of what you actually did. And include what OS/dist you're using.

Comment: i have update my question.

Answer (score 0):

See the referenced config file for paths to log files.

Inspect the log files for error messages.